# OSGI module version conflict

Tags: maven, osgi, eclipse-rcp, osgi-bundle, tycho

Eclipse RCP has been packaged as maven.
I packaged it to run on Windows, and when I ran the program, the following error occurred and the program did not run.
I think there was a version conflict between modules in the OSGI environment, so can I get a hint on what settings I need to modify?

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.cubrid.common.update [4]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations; bundle-version="2.5.800.v20200410-1336"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations [93]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director
           -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director"; bundle-version="2.4.700.v20200511-1530"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations,  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.tools,  org.eclipse.pde.core,  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins,  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui,  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director.app"
              org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director [82]
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.configurator
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui; bundle-version="2.6.0.v20200602-1138"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui [102]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.configurator
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director
           -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director"; bundle-version="2.4.700.v20200511-1530"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations,  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.tools,  org.eclipse.pde.core,  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins,  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui,  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director.app"
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.operations
           -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.operations; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations"; bundle-version="2.5.800.v20200410-1336"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.pde.ui,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1838)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1743)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1665)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

What configuration file should I share? If you let me know, I will share additional files.

Comment: I think the failure to find the `org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.configurator
` package is probably the issue - that is in the `org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator` plug-in - is that included?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

Is the org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator plugin version incorrect?
I still don't have enough knowledge about Eclipse RCP, so I'm not sure what part I should fix.
Is there any material I can refer to?
I would appreciate it if you could give me some hints.

Comment: I have additional questions.

When I run debug in Eclipse IDE, the program runs, but why can't I package it with maven and then run the exe?

Comment: As far as I can tell from this org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator is missing altogether which suggests that something in the build information given to tycho is wrong, possibly the target platform info, but diagnosing tycho build errors without the complete project is very difficult. Maybe look at a [tycho tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html) to get a better idea of how it works.

Comment: The error occurred because a tag was missing from the .product file....
Thank you so much for your help in resolving the issue!!